# Why is my clothing simulation strange？

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

I am doing a simulation of clothing. The clothing which is .obj format was exported from CLO3d(a clothing design software). I have processed the .obj file and it only contains Vertex items, Face items, and Line items(this can be used for sewing). I want to dress it onto a human body, but the result seems so strange when compared to [Blender | Sewing Cloth In Blender 2.83 | Beginners Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h89tkUJLuM). Hope someone can give me some advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try turning up the cloth steps, changing the collision distance of the cloth and the body. Try changing the cloth settings to silk or other things to see if that helps.

Comment: Are your normals consistent? Is the collision margin set too high?